# use of while True in code

Tags: language-agnostic, while-loop

I'm a relatively new programmer and many a times I have seen expert programmers writing a piece of code under the expression

```
while True
```

I am confused what significance does it make? Is it used to execute that part of code which is necessary to be executed or is it just a convention?

Comment: This should answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6850380/are-whiletrue-loops-so-bad

Comment: possible duplicate of [is while(true) bad programming practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/390481/is-whiletrue-bad-programming-practice)

Comment: @jkbkot It's slightly different IMO. The one you linked to is comparing and contrasting with `while (condition)` whereas this one is asking more broadly. (Although if the OP meant "as opposed to `while (condition)` then I suppose it is a duplicate after all.)

Comment: @starsplusplus true, I was thinking about it too. I linked it because some of the answers and comments address the OP's point too - e.g. the use of while (true) in multitrheading, etc.

Comment: Yes, the OP might well find it useful/interesting. :)

Answer (score 4):

In some cases it is desirable, for the condition to always evaluate to true, creating an infinite loop.

```
while(true)
{
    //do your work here in loop
}
```

When such a loop is created intentionally, there is usually another control structure (such as a `break` statement) that controls termination of the loop. For example:

```
while (true) 
{
   //do complicated stuff
   if (someCondition) break;
   //more stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That means infinite loop. So if you want to use this, you have to put a code inside, to get out of this loop (break, return), otherwise your code will be in this loop forever..
Check:[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6719630/how-to-escape-a-while-loop-in-c-sharp)